# появление блока при нажатии на сниппет

Tags: javascript

У меня есть текст (сниппет) при нажатии на который должен появляться блок.
Гуглила, нашла библиотеку "Tooltip", но, насколько я поняла, эта бибилиотека решает мою задачу только если всплывающий блок будет иметь текстовый контент, а мне нужно чтобы всплывающий после нажатия на сниппет блок мог содержать любой контент.
**Важно!** Реализовать это мне нужно **на чистом  js**.
Подскажите, есть ли какие-то библиотеки, или как иначе можно реализовать такое?

Cпасибо.

Comment: popper js _(4 символа нужно...)_

Answer (score 0):

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.tooltip .tooltipContent {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 200px;
  top: 18px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: none;
}


.tooltip:hover .tooltipContent {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
бла бла бла 
<span class="tooltip">
  сюда можно навести
  <div class="tooltipContent">
    Проверка, тут можно вставлять любой html
  </div>
</span>
бла бла бла <br>
бла бла бла
```

Comment: Просмотрел что при клике надо, тогда наверное только js, можно тултип просто скрывать и показывать по клику